# Select distinct using LINQ but base distinct on another column

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

How should I select distinct using LINQ when there is an object similar to following:

```
public class foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }    
}
```

The list could be:

```
 id = 1, lang = "en", name="test1"
 id = 1, lang = "fr", name="test2"
 id = 1, lang = "de", name="test3"
 id = 2, lang = "en", name="test4"
 id = 2, lang = "fr", name="test5"
 id = 3, lang = "en", name="test6"
 id = 3, lang = "fr", name="test7"
 id = 4, lang = "en", name="test8"
 id = 5, lang = "de", name="test9"
```

I want to run LINQ so that it returns distinct id values, but the distinct id values should be filtered based on lang 
e.g. "fr", should retrieve following results:

```
 id = 1, lang = "fr", name="test2"
 id = 2, lang = "fr", name="test5"
 id = 3, lang = "fr", name="test7"
 id = 4, lang = "en", name="test8"
 id = 5, lang = "de", name="test9"
```

All of you LINQ experts, I'm ideally looking for query using lambda, this would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sound more like simple `Where` rather than `Distinct`.

Comment: `foos.Where(x => x.lang == "fr")`

Comment: Thanks Evan & Jason. I've changed the description, I need to retrieve the other records if there is no "fr" record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the items by `id` and from each group, take the first item sorted by `lang != "fr"`. This will make the "fr" items float to the top of each group (`false` sorts before `true`):

```
list.GroupBy(f => f.id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => f.lang != "fr").FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: To tackle the "cannot convert" error you should show your original code. That's not directly related to LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
foos.GroupBy(el => el.id)
    .Select(gr => new
        {
            foo = gr.Any(el => el.lang == "fr") ? gr.FirstOrDefault(el => el.lang == "fr") : gr.FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

Comment: Executes two iterations per group. If you do `gr.FirstOrDefault(el => el.lang == "fr") ?? gr.FirstOrDefault()` this will be reduced to one or two iterations per group.

Comment: Hi Tim & Gert, Thanks, it seems to be returning null at the moment, so not sure if I'm using the correct syntax:
   IQueryable<SearchResultPage> allIndexCenters = ContentService.GetAllCenters();
            IQueryable<SearchResultPage> allCenters = null;
            allIndexCenters.GroupBy(x => x.FREDID)
                            .Select(gr => new
                            {
                                allCenters = gr.Any(el => el.Language == "fr") ? gr.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Language == "fr") : gr.FirstOrDefault()
                            }).AsQueryable();

Comment: When I tried the following:
            var allCenters = allIndexCenters.GroupBy(x => x.FREDID)
                            .Select(gr => new
                            {
                                SearchResultCentrePage = gr.Any(el => el.Language == "fr") ? gr.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Language == "fr") : gr.FirstOrDefault()
                            }).AsQueryable();
       
       
    I get errorm msg: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: Search.SearchResultPage SearchResultPage>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Search.SearchResultPage>'

Comment: Guys, I'm not a LINQ expert, please could you give me a direction, because the code looks exactly what I want.